# Change Default Layout in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, debian, shell

It is probably a simple problem, but I can't think of anythig else to goolge to figure it out myself.

I am using gnome terminal, which I have added to mx-linux. By default, it looks like this:

```
user@computer:~
$ echo some command
some command
```

I don't like the dollar-sign being in a seperate line. I want it to look like this:

```
philmx@philmx:~$ echo some command
some command
```

I'm currently on debian-based MX Linux.

From what I've been able to figure out, it is probably something to edit in `~/.bash.rc` ? But what...

Comment: what you are looking for to modify is the bash prompt. Search for *change bash prompt*. Also, it is not related to the terminal you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for to modify is the shell **prompt**. It is stored in the environment variable `PS1`. You can do `echo $PS1` to see your actual prompt.

If you want to remove the newline character, just remove it from the result of `echo PS1` and set `PS1` in your *.bashrc* (the newline character is represented by the sequence `\n`).

Here is an example, add the `export PS1=...` to your bashrc (*$HOME/.bashrc*) once you are satisfied with your prompt.

```bsh
user@host:~
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\
[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$  
user@host:~
$ export PS1=\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
user@host:~$ echo I removed the newline from the prompt, add the same line to your bashrc
I removed the newline from the prompt, add the same line to your bashrc
user@host:~$
```

Note: The weird character sequences like `\[\033[01;32m\]` are escape codes, mainly for colours.
See a tutorial on customizing bash prompt if you want to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks. Command Prompt was the term I was missing. Once I googled it, I came upon this neat website that let's you customize the command prompt very easily http://ezprompt.net/  thanks!